# Sinus Pattern analysis

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, signal-detection, signal-power, waveform-similarity

i have 1000 data which range between 50 and 180 ( heart BPM data in a day) how can i measure its similarity to a Sinus pattern?

for example, for 20th recorded data (for example it is 60BPM), evaluate whether it is in sinus pattern or incoherent rhythm pattern.
i need to quantify sinus pattern similarity with my own number, where this number is the result of a formula function in excel. It doesn't matter how i calculate but it is important that the generated number has infinite range band.

(which Max here means real-time value (bpm) is in very pure sinus pattern and coherent / and Min means in chaos and very incoherent pattern)

Note: I really appreciate if you put a function formula here in order to copy/past in my Excel, then convert my data column into that range number.